# add comma after each 2 chars in string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace, split

A column such as the following, how do I write a query in a way that still have to put in one column to a comma to search two characters.

Example;

'aa, aa, aa, aa, aa, aa, aa, aa, aa, aa' to be.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Looked at this a half dozen times and I simply cannot grasp what you are are attempting. Could you rephrase the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the tsql script below to insert ", " in every 2 character:

```
DECLARE @Char VARCHAR(800) = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' --sample data

DECLARE @TotalChar INT = LEN(@Char)
DECLARE @Counter INT = @TotalChar

WHILE @Counter >= 1
BEGIN

    IF @Counter % 2 = 0 AND @Counter + 1 <= @TotalChar
    BEGIN
        SET @Char = STUFF(@Char, @Counter + 1, 0, ', ')
    END

    SET @Counter = @Counter - 1
END

SELECT @Char --result data
```

Answer (score 4):

another one approach using `recursive cte` and `for xml`:

```
declare @tbl as table (id int, field varchar(200))
insert into @tbl 
values (1, 'aabbccddeeffgghhgg'),
       (2, 'aabbccddeeffgghhgg')
    
;with cte 
      as (select id, field, n = 1
          from @tbl
          union all
          select id, field, n = n + 1
          from cte
          where n < len(field))

     select distinct a.id,
            stuff((select ',' + substring(b.field,b.n,2)
                   from    cte AS b
                   where   b.id = a.iD and b.n%2 = 1
                   order by b.id, b.n
                   for XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS Field
     from cte as a
```

**[test is here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/412647)**